# Unable to create a "Single" entry

Tags: entries, control-panel

I haven't made a new single in a few years, it seems. Now when I try to create one, there is no option to do so. Normally, the *New Entry* button seems to be split, with the left part directly creating a new entry in the currently selected channel or structure, and the right part giving a drop-down with the various channels and structures available. However the drop-down does not include *Singles*, and if I have *Singles* highlighted, then the *New Entry* button doesn't have the left part, just the drop-down.

Also, if I try to edit an existing single, there is no option to save as a new entry or save and add another. Any thoughts?

Comment: The functionality you want should really be a structure or channel. Put very basically singles are for one-off pages, like the home page for example. Entries that will have no similar type content anywhere else. Structures are for multiple entries of the same sort of content (and can be hierarchical with parents and children) such as an about section. Channels are for 'repeating' content, such as news entries where they're not hierarchical but just ordered in some way, usually reverse date. [more about section types](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/sections-and-entries.html#section-types)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should create a new single in the "Section" area of the settings page. It should just create the single after you have created the section.